# What is the best way to test methods that traverse the react components

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I have tried to test small react components. The following component is a tab system that when click a tab, change the className of the tab was clicked. It is working but I want to test them and I dont know how is the steps to test a method that traverse a lot of components. I put the code above.

TabSystem: Has a method to change the currentTab state, this method is as prop in the tabs component that renders each tab.

```
React.createClass({
  ....
  handleClick (currentTab) {
    this.setState({ currentTab })
  },

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Tabs tabs = {tabs2} currentTab = {this.state.currentTab} onClick = {this.handleClick}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Tabs: Receive into onClick prop the parent method, this method is as prop into tab component, my goal is to add the onClick method only in the name of the tab.

```
React.createClass({
  ...
  renderTabs () {
    return this.props.tabs.map((tab, index) => {
      var classname = index === this.props.currentTab ? 'active' : null;
      var clickHandler = this.props.onClick.bind(null, index);
      return (
        <Tab key={tab.name} onClick={clickHandler} index={index} className={classname} name={tab.name}/>
      )
    })
  },
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderTabs()}
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Tab: Receive again into onClick prop the parent method.

```
React.createClass({
  render () {
    return (
      <span className={this.props.className} onClick={this.props.onClick}>
        {this.props.name}
      </span>
    )
  }
});
```

What is the best way to test this method? Do I need in all components the method that works well?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a testing library that abstracts React's test utils. https://github.com/Legitcode/tests You can do something like:

```
Test(<TestComponent />)
.find('button')
.simulate({method: 'click', element: 'button'})
.element(button => {
  expect(button.props.className).to.be.equal('blah');
})
```

You get the idea, hopefully that helps.